# WPF DataGrid not displaying data with DataTemplate and DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel 
{
   public string TestField { get; set; }  

   public ObservableCollection<object> TestCollection { get; set; }  

   public ViewModel()
   {
       TestField  = "ABCD";
   }
}
```

I want to use different DataGridTemplateColumns depending on the value of TestField. The DataGrid will have TestCollection as its ItemSource, and within the DataTemplate, I want to use an item from the ItemSource. However, the choice of DataTemplate needs to depend on TestField. **The issue is that TestField is outside the context of TestCollection.**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a converter to bind the TestField property to the CellTemplate property.
If the TestField property can change after the ViewModel instance is created, then it is necessary to provide notification of its change through the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event. In my example, this is done through the methods of the ViewModelBase base class:

```cs
public class TestFieldViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string TestField { get => Get<string>(); set => Set(value); }

    public ObservableCollection<object> TestCollection { get; /*set;*/ } = new();

    public TestFieldViewModel()
    {
        foreach (var item in "Example")
        {
            TestCollection.Add(item);
        }

        // асинхронная смена значения с целью тестирования
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                TestField = "ABCD";
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                TestField = string.Empty;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```cs
public class TestFieldTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public DataTemplate Default { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ABCD { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value switch
        {
            "ABCD" => ABCD,
            _ => Default
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window ----------------------------
        ----------------------------
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TestFieldViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="default">
                    <TextBlock Text="Default"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ABCD">
                    <TextBlock Text="ABCD"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <local:TestFieldTemplateConverter
                    x:Key="templateConverter"
                    Default="{StaticResource default}"
                    ABCD="{StaticResource ABCD}"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn
                    CellTemplate="{Binding TestField,
                                           Source={StaticResource vm},
                                           Converter={StaticResource templateConverter}}">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I didn’t succeed as you suggest, but you gave me the idea to use
                                 <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding DataContext.Access1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Converter={StaticResource templateConverter}}" />

Comment: @ПавелЗакриев , The specific implementation depends on many details. Including the way in which the Data Context for the DataGrid is set. Your question did not provide all the necessary details. Therefore, my example is a conceptual solution that needs to be adapted to the detailed conditions of your actual task.

Comment: You can communicate in Russian, right?
Then you better ask questions here: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/

Comment: please tell me, do I understand correctly that in this case the converter will work for each line?
Поэтому я пометил ваш ответ как верный! Спасибо

Comment: @ПавелЗакриев , Since the TestField property is common to all rows, the converter will supply the same DataTemplate for each row. When you change the TestField property, the DataTemplate of all rows will be changed.

Comment: Yes, it’s clear that it will provide the same Datatemplate, but if there are a lot of rows, will it process each one?

Comment: @ПавелЗакриев , It passes the value to the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplat property. The function of transferring (synchronizing) DataTemplate Cells with this property is already the responsibility of the DataGridTemplateColumn. Therefore, when changing the value of the TestField property, the converter will be called once. But all cells will receive this template from the DataGridTemplateColumn automatically.